# How to manage css files the best way

Tags: css, performance

A question about performance.

I have a web project with different CSS files at the moment (uncompressed). Every page is including the needed files.

I am thinking about putting all style definitions in one file, compressing it, and putting it central in the header.

What makes for a better performance? One file compressed (every page loads all styles), or to split the files and only load the needed ones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Splitting the files up will require the browser to do more requests - in the long run, this is probably slower than if you put up one stylesheet that is reused for all the pages. Once the browser has the stylesheet, it will be stored in the browsercache. For all pages after the first, the browser won't need to download the stylesheets. In the end I think this gives a better user experience.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Although I think we're forgetting print stylesheets?

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will try to put everything in one file, and compress it with something like yui-compressor!

Answer (score 3):

We typically keep all of our CSS file separate under development, then when it comes to deploy, we pack them together into a single file, and use gzip compression on the server to send them compressed to the client.

Comment: You can even take it further by minifying the CSS itself, see for example: http://dimebrain.com/2008/03/a-better-css-mi.html

Answer (score 1):

One compressed file will probably be fastest. You want to cut down on HTTP requests. Also try and put all background images into one file and use css sprites.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of website,

- if it is an intranet website where the users are probably using every-page on the site then pre-loading all the css will be the fastest.
- if it is an internet website where most users will go away after a few clicks then I would use smaller css file per page.

Have a look at [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#css_top) and [Google Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rtt.html#CombineExternalCSS) for more tips.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working in an environment where we're working with the public stylesheets in uncompressed separate files, and then they're automatically merged and compressed into a single file. As it's compressed, it's obviously less size and loads faster, but it's even better when it's only one file since there will only be one connection to the server when fetching the stylesheets (each CSS file requires 1 connection) and then it will remain cached in the users browser.